# Unity GameObject velocity and animation issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity so please bear with me.

**What I want to do:**

I want my simple game object to have a linear speed on Z axis (white path on the screenshot) and perform a simple animation while this object is moving

So I have attached rigidbody to my green game object and attach a script to it and get the required component and set velocity to 10f.

```
myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector3 (0,0,10f);
```

This works and the object starts moving when I hit "play" in Unity editor.

[image]

**The problem:**

If "Animator" component on this game object is checked, the player won't move (but it will perform animation). When I uncheck this component the game object will start to move.

In the animation itself, I'm changing the position of game object (Y axis - jump), and rotation (will flip).

**The question:**

Why my game object won't move (even that I've given it a linear velocity), when the animator component is checked (in action)?

I want this game object to be moving and on click perform an animation.

This is basically it. Any help highly appreciated.

EDIT: Animation values:

[image]

Comment: Did you checked if animation does not overrides rigidbody's properties?

Comment: Please see my edit. Any chance there Is something wrong with values?

Comment: So you're changing it's position in animation. That's why rigidbody cannot "push" your object.

Comment: Yes because I want to "jump". Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: If you want to just "jump" then do not change `X` and `Z` values in the animation. You should change only the `Y` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome the fact that Unity overrides the Rigidbody when an Animator is attached by creating a new empty GameObject and making it the parent of the existing (animating) GameObject.

I found this information on the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/animation-stops-object-movement.184084/).